How to mark snoozed email as unread with google app scripts?
We are many asking google to have an option to mark un-snoozed email as unread in Gmail but unfortunatly this is not happening. I am talking of those emails.
ChatGPT proposed to use google-app-scripts but I didn't find the right API to spot which email has been un-snoozed in a time interval (like last 7 days).

Here is the code proposed by ChatGPT, however snoozed is not a label, could it be improved to work? Thank you
function markUnsnoozedEmailsAsUnread() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:inbox -label:snoozed'); // Search for un-snoozed emails in the inbox
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    
    // Check if the thread has the 'snoozed' label
    var labels = thread.getLabels();
    var hasSnoozedLabel = labels.some(function(label) {
      return label.getName() === 'snoozed';
    });
    
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      if (!message.isUnread() && hasSnoozedLabel) {
        message.markUnread(); // Mark email as unread if it's not already and not snoozed
      }
    }
  }
}


Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function markUnsnoozedEmailsAsUnread() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:snoozed');
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var thread = threads[i];
    var messages = thread.getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message = messages[j];
      if (!message.isUnread()) {
        message.markUnread();
      }
    }
  }
}

In this modified script, the emails searched by in:snoozed are set as unread.
Note:

Or, as another approach, how about the following modification?
function markUnsnoozedEmailsAsUnread() {
  GmailApp.search('in:snoozed').forEach(thread =>
    thread.getMessages().forEach(message => {
      if (!message.isUnread()) {
        message.markUnread();
      }
    })
  );
}

function markUnsnoozedEmailsAsUnread() {
  GmailApp.search('in:snoozed').forEach(thread => {
    if (!thread.isUnread()) {
      thread.markUnread();
    }
  });
}



Reference:

Refine searches in Gmail


Thanks so much, "in:snoozed" query is matching threads that are in snoozed state, not ex-snoozed threads that went back to inbox with a special orange mention 'snoozed XX ago' (like in the screenshot I provided). I looked carefully in the link you provided and it seems there is no query to match those threads :(

@Patrick from NDepend team Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I could understand that you wanted to set emails, that were finished to snooze, as unread. Although I'm not sure whether this is appropriate for your situation, in this case, how about modifying the search query from in:snoozed to label:pinned and testing it again? Before running the script, you can test the search query in the Gmail interface on your browser. But if this was not useful for your situation, I apologize again.

Mark un-snoozed emails as unread
Upon doing some research, there seem to have no straight-forward way to get those email that were recently un-snoozed and do things with them e.g marking them as unread but  this is an alternative way that you can consider. This approach uses Google Apps Script and a Google Sheet that serves a “database” that stores the email id of snoozed emails and then checks if an email got un-snoozed(in inbox again) by checking if the ids in the sheet is present in the inbox, if so, the script will mark that email as unread.
On the first run of this script, it will get all the emails currently in:snoozed and paste those emails’s ids in the specified sheet.
Script
function markUnsnoozedEmailsAsUnread() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Use_your_actual_id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Use_Actual_sheet_name");

  var snoozedIdsRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var snoozedIds = snoozedIdsRange.getValues().flat().filter(id => id);

    if (snoozedIds.length === 0) {
    var snoozed = GmailApp.search('in:snoozed');
    snoozedIds = snoozed.map(email => email.getId());

    if (snoozedIds.length > 0) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, snoozedIds.length, 1).setValues(snoozedIds.map(id => [id]));
    }
  }

  var snoozedIdsRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var snoozedIds = snoozedIdsRange.getValues().flat().filter(id => id);
  
  var inboxed = GmailApp.search('in:inbox');
  var inboxedIds = inboxed.map(email => email.getId());
  
  for (var j = 0; j < snoozedIds.length; j++) {
    if (inboxedIds.includes(snoozedIds[j])) {
      Logger.log("Found in inbox, attempting to mark as unread: " + snoozedIds[j]);
      try {
        var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(snoozedIds[j]);
        if (message) {
          if (!message.isUnread()) {
            message.markUnread();
            Logger.log("Successfully marked as unread: " + snoozedIds[j]);
            sheet.clear();
          } else {
            Logger.log("Already unread: " + snoozedIds[j]);
            sheet.clear();
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log("Message not found for ID: " + snoozedIds[j]);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log("Error marking as unread for ID: " + snoozedIds[j] + " - " + e.message);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log("Not found in inbox: " + snoozedIds[j]);
    }
  }
}

Just paste this code on apps script editor and create a spreadsheet that will serve as the storage of ids
Outputs
in:snoozed email

On the first run emails on snoozed will be fetch and it's ids will be stored on the sheet
Emails that got un:snoozed

Once an email got unsnoozed, and once again on your inbox, run the script again to mark those emails as unread
Unread after unsnoozing and running the script again

After unsnoozing(manually) an email then running the script again, the email will be marked as unread.

This is an alternative that you may try, please feel free to give feedback
